# Ejs page not rendering on the simplified version of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lodash, ejs

This code renders the 'post' page:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res) {
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

    if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
      res.render('post');
    }
  });
```

But when I simplify it to this:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res) {

  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    if (req.params.postName === _.lowerCase(post.title)) {
      res.render('post');
    }
  });
```

The 'post' page is no longer rendered. Could anyone please explain why? Also, I only just recently began learning javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the possible reason behind this is that in the code:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res) {
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

    if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
      res.render('post');
    }
  });
```

You are converting both `"req.params.postName"`  and `"post.title"` to lowe case and the you are checking if they are equal or not but in the code:

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res) {

  posts.forEach(function(post) {
    if (req.params.postName === _.lowerCase(post.title)) {
      res.render('post');
    }
  });
```

You are only converting post.title to lower case. So change the statement:

`if (req.params.postName === _.lowerCase(post.title)) {`

to

`if (_.lowerCase(req.params.postName) === _.lowerCase(post.title))`

And one more thing I am not sure how your schema is set but if you are allowing multiple posts with same title, then you will get an error of "Cannot read headers". Either use
`return res.render(post)` or use the route via id instead of a post Name as it is not a really good practice.

And hopefully it should work.